# What's the maximum temperature of quicklime slaking?

Tags: kinetics

Normally the maximum temperature of lime slaking is listed at about 100 C. I've read that using water with high salt concentrations will catalyze the slaking reaction and increase the boiling point thereby leading to higher slaking temperatures.

If you performed the slaking operation in a pressurized chamber this should increase the boiling point. Would it also lead to higher slaking temperatures

Comment: The purpose of "slaking" is to re-hydrate CaO, which was made from CaCO3 by heating.  Why would one want to *raise* the temperature of this (already exothermic) step?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni, perhaps to *provide* heat?